# How to add class to objects greater then count?

Tags: php, html, for-loop, foreach, laravel-blade

blade and I have created a foreach loop which adds a class to divs if number of divs is greater then 3. I only want to add this class to the objects greater then 3 and not to the divs less then 3. How would I do this?

```
@if(!empty($property->testimonials))
    @foreach($property->testimonials as $testimonial)
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <div @if ($i == count($testimonial) > 3) class="displayNoneTesty" @endif>
        <h3 class="black tworem blue">
            {{ $testimonial->citation }}
        </h3>
        <p class="black marginBottomNone">
            20/04/2018
        </p>
        <p> 
            {{ mb_strimwidth(strip_tags($testimonial->body), 0, 300, '...') }}
        </p>
    </div>
     <?php $i++; ?> 
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Blade has special `$loop` variable, you can use `$loop->iteration` to get current iteration number (starts from 1):

```
@if(!empty($property->testimonials))
    @foreach($property->testimonials as $testimonial)
    <div @if ($loop->iteration > 3) class="displayNoneTesty" @endif>
        <h3 class="black tworem blue">
            {{ $testimonial->citation }}
        </h3>
        <p class="black marginBottomNone">
            20/04/2018
        </p>
    </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Nice one thank you, I will accept answer as soon as I can.